# can't clone the repository because of the space in the paths

Tags: git, github, git-clone

When I trying clone repo, I get an error path in console.
The problem only on Windows, on Ubuntu I can clone w/o errors and its ok.
I see that spaces in repo between path __tests and /index.js
How can I clone it?

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 573, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (573/573), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (223/223), done.
remote: Total 124067 (delta 422), reused 416 (delta 338), pack-reused 123494R
Receiving objects: 100% (124067/124067), 26.59 MiB | 4.13 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (83046/83046), done.
error: invalid path '/server/__tests__ /index.js'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.        
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Comment: You may want to report this at https://github.com/git-for-windows/git.

Comment: What does your clone command look like? `git clone...`

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of Windows.  It does not typically permit paths with trailing spaces, and your repository has a path with one.

That file won't be able to checked out on a regular Windows file system, so you have some options:

- Rename the directory, commit, and push it to the remote server, if you have access to do so.  You can use `git mv -f "server/__tests__ " "server/__tests__"`.
- Explain the situation to the project maintainer and ask them to rename it.
- Deal with the fact that this path won't work on Windows.
- Use Windows Subsystem for Linux or a Linux box to check it out.
- Convince Microsoft to fix this problem in Windows.